# ASP.NET MVC kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-grid

I can populate the items in the grid only when I pass the Model directly. If I try to get Json data I can't.

Here is my Controller:

```
namespace MVC_Test1.Controllers
{
    public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        private ContosoUniversityEntities db = new ContosoUniversityEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return View(db.students.ToList());
        }


        public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            using (var northwind = new ContosoUniversityEntities())
            {
                IQueryable<student> students = northwind.students;
                DataSourceResult result = students.ToDataSourceResult(request);

                return Json(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I have this View the grid works and shows all the items:

```
@model MVC_Test1.Models.student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@*@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
    })
)*@
```

But if I try to read from json it doesn't work. It shows an empty grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MVC_Test1.Models.student>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Students"))
    )
)
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for helping.

Comment: It could be because you are using an `IQueryable` instead of `List`

Comment: Do you get any errors in browser console? Does your request hit the action?

Comment: I have changed to use a List and still no data. No errors and yes, it is hitting the action and I see it is retrieving data but the list still empty...this is very strange

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that much problem either. But try three things, allow get.

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Secondly, I don't think it is a problem but try using List instead of IQueryable.

Lastly, try return **JsonResult** instead of ***ActionResult***.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does it hit backend? I mean the Read() function in Students controller. It does return value, right??

Comment: [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) *is* an ActionResult (it's a derived type), but using a more specific return type doesn't really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after trying everything (thanks to all of you) I started a new proyect and it worked. I don't know what was wrong, but now it is working. Thanks